# Нагрузочное тестирование чата

Tags: highload, socket.io, websocket, тестирование

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно узнать сколько сообщений успевает пересылать сервер в секунду и при каком объеме сообщений он начинает тупить, выдавая пользователям 502 ошибку.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем обычно тестируют чаты, чтобы узнать, нужную мне, информацию. Красивые графики и отчеты приветствуются. Для соединения клиент-сервера используется socket.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня была когда то подобная задача. Я сделал следующее.

На perl (просто я его знаю), написал минимального клиента, который просто логинился и посылал сообщения раз в секунду. Потом, отдельно написал bash-скрипт (это все происходило в линуксе), который просто запускал по сотне подобных скриптов. Часть скриптов умели логиниться с заведомо неверными паролями.

А дальше просто - запустил одной командой сотню клиентов и смотришь, как сервер себя чувствует, записал параметры. Потом ещё сотню набросил. (хотя, смотря что за чат - может там по 1000 нужно будет набрасывать). Сервер вел логи, которые потом консольными утилитами анализировались (опять же, на перл:) ). Как то так.

Comment: сам я работаю с питоном и тоже проживаю в линуксе, поэтому примерно такой вариант и рассматривал как запасной. но, наверное, есть что-то общепринятое и признанное?
вся соль еще в том, что провернуть такое дело нужно за завтра (и ночь, судя по всему) и писать свои тесты совсем нет времени. может, поделитесь своими наработками, если не жалко и еще что-то осталось?

Comment: мой клиент Вам точно не подойдет. (у меня был свой специфический протокол. Запустить сотню клиентов в консольке просто (ещё и номерок передаем)

    for i in $(seq 100); do echo $i; ./client -n $i done

Если у Вас ещё нет рабочего просто клиента - то решить задачу будет очень сложно.

Но раз Вы пишете о 502 ошибке, то подозреваю, что там http чат. И значит, можно потестить обычными http запросами. А для этого есть готовая утилита - [ab](http://jokerov.com/testirovanie/nagruzochnoe-testirovanie-sajta-apache-benchmark/). Хотя есть много других.